# Simple If else unable to get work

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have two textbox named txtA,txtB

```
var count;//which needs to be compared with BValue
var AValue = $("#txtA").val();
var BValue = $("#txtB").val();

 if (AValue  == "") {
            alert("Enter AValue and continue");
        } else if (BValue  == "") {
            alert("Enter To BValue and continue");
        } else if (AValue  > BValue ) {
            alert("AValue should be lesser than To BValue");
        } else if (AValue == "" || BValue == "") {
            alert("Please enter the AValue and BValue to continue");
        } else if (AValue == "0") {
            alert("Invalid AValue");
        } else if (BValue  > count) {
            alert("Invalid BValue");
        } else {
             // do some operations here
        }
```

All the conditions are passing well but this `BValue > count` is triggering me though it satisfy the conditions

Comment: I think you forgot to close the parenthesis. As such: if ($("Value ==""))

Comment: i dont see `BValue > count` in OP

Comment: syntax error at if ($("AValue  == "").  it should be  if (AValue == "")

Comment: even your pagecount variable is undefined you have used in last else if condition.

Comment: this OP shouldn't come from someone with so much reputation.

Comment: @guardio when i checked his profile I thought he will not be having any experience in Javascript or JQuery but he has gained several points in those areas.

Comment: @AmitRay actually it is just an if/else condition.. no matter what language you use you can see the error that right? problem is not with language he just didnt bother to check properly.. just saying

Comment: @guradio Obviously this is not language specific.

Comment: Sorry guys its a typo in my question ($("AValue  == "") { should be ("AValue  == "") { and for pagecount its mentioned as count which was updated now..As per the answers its the same showing me the alert Invalid BValue

Comment: You have not assigned any value to 'count'. So what exactly is the value of count that you are comparing the BValue to? Coz if you won't assign any value at the time of declaration or before comparing it with BValue, then a random value will be assigned to it, which can be greater than BValue as well as smaller.

Comment: @Ankush the value will be populated automatically and I get the count value when clicked the button

Comment: In that case, you'll have to show us the complete javascript code, so that we can see from where and how your 'count' variable is picking up the value from the HTML. Only then we'll be able to help you. Coz right now, according the code you've given us, your 'count' variable is simply declared at one place, which means a random value is being assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Either use:

```
if ( AValue == ""){

}
```

Or

```
if ( ($("#txtA").val()) == "" ){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this Working example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="txtA" name="txtA">
    <input type="text" id="txtB" name="txtB">

    <button onclick="CheckVal()" type="button"> Check It </button>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function CheckVal(){

                var count;//which needs to be compared with BValue
                var AValue = $("#txtA").val();
                var BValue = $("#txtB").val();

                 if (AValue == "") {
                            alert("Enter AValue and continue");
                        } else if (BValue  == "") {
                            alert("Enter To BValue and continue");
                        } else if (AValue  > BValue ) {
                            alert("AValue should be lesser than To BValue");
                        } else if (AValue == "" || BValue == "") {
                            alert("Please enter the AValue and BValue to continue");
                        } else if (AValue == "0") {
                            alert("Invalid AValue");
                        } else if (BValue  > count) {
                            alert("Invalid To Page Number");
                        } else {
                             // do some operations here
                             alert("This is Else Part");
                        }
                }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```